# How do I deploy a Python desktop application?

Tags: python, deployment

I have started on a personal python application that runs on the desktop. I am using wxPython as a GUI toolkit. Should there be a demand for this type of application, I would possibly like to commercialize it.

I have no knowledge of deploying "real-life" Python applications, though I have used [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) in the past with varied success. How would I obfuscate the code? Can I somehow deploy only the bytecode?

An ideal solution would not jeopardize my intellectual property (source code), would not require a direct installation of Python (though I'm sure it will need to have some embedded interpreter), and would be cross-platform (Windows, Mac, and Linux). Does anyone know of any tools or resources in this area?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you protect python code ? Well ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code/261817#261817

Answer (score 15):

You can distribute the compiled Python bytecode (.pyc files) instead of the source. You can't prevent decompilation in Python (or any other language, really). You could use an obfuscator like [pyobfuscate](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~astrand/projects/pyobfuscate/) to make it more annoying for competitors to decipher your decompiled source.

As Alex Martelli says [in this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-April/1079623.html), if you want to keep your code a secret, you shouldn't run it on other people's machines.

IIRC, the last time I used [cx_Freeze](http://python.net/crew/atuining/cx_Freeze/) it created a DLL for Windows that removed the necessity for a native Python installation. This is at least worth checking out.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe IronPython can provide something for you? I bet those .exe/.dll-files can be pretty locked down. Not sure how such features work on mono, thus no idea how this works on Linux/OS X...

Answer (score 2):

Wow, there are a lot of questions in there:

- It is possible to run the bytecode (.pyc) file directly from the Python interpreter, but I haven't seen any bytecode obfuscation tools available.
- I'm not aware of any "all in one" deployment solution, but:

  - For Windows you could use NSIS(http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).  The problem here is that while OSX/*nix comes with python, Windows doesn't.  If you're not willing to build a binary with py2exe, I'm not sure what the licensing issues would be surrounding distribution of the Python runtime environment (not to mention the technical ones).
  - You could package up the OS X distribution using the "bundle" format, and *NIX has it's own conventions for installing software-- typically a "make install" script.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Python's bytecode is very high level and trivially decompileable; distributing .pyc files is really not any form of protection you want to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using py2exe with good success on Windows. The code needs to be modified a bit so that the code analysis picks up all modules needed, but apart from that, it works.

As for Linux, there are several important distribution formats:

- DEB (Debian, Ubuntu and other derivatives)
- RPM (RedHat, Fedora, openSuSE)

DEBs aren't particularly difficult to make, especially when you're already using distutils/setuptools. Some hints are given in [the policy document](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianPython/NewPolicy), examples for packaging Python applications can be found in the [repository](http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/python-apps/packages/).

I don't have any experience with RPM, but I'm sure there are enough examples to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scraZ obfuscator (http://scraZ.me).
This is obfuscator for bytecode, not for source code.
Free version have good, but not perfect obfuscation methods.
PRO version have very very strong protection for bytecode.
(after bytecode obfuscation a decompilation is impossible)