# Is there a way i could restrict class variables to be accessed by objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Class sampleclass:
      constant = 10
def __init(self,value)
      self.value = value *10 + constant


x = sampleclass(2)
print (x.value) #prints the calculated value
print(x.constant) #prints the constant
```

Question: I do not want 'x' to access 'constant' value, How can i restrict this or is there any other way to declare constant?

Answer (score 0):

**Python is not designed to do this as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483366/protected-method-in-python).**

But if you really want that you have to override the getter and setter of the constant.

In your case you could do this:

```
class Sampleclass:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value * 10 + self.constant

    @property
    def constant(self):
        return 10
```

The @property constant returns the integer 10

because is only a @property without a corrosponding setter you cannot change the value

Comment: There is no need to add a setter just to throw an error. A missing setter already throws an error on assignment.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will edit it!