# Licensing web applications

Tags: web-applications, licensing, piracy-prevention

If I want to sell a web application as an installable product on the customer's servers, what are the best method practices for enforcing licensing such that it's not easily ripped and pirated?

Comment: Trust and offering installation support service, or even "drop in" servers pre-configured. You could put in phone-home capability (which they could block if they find out about it), or you could just charge site-wide. Putting effort into features and so on instead of protection is logical in my mind. Depends on the resources available to you really...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered a few times before [How to create a secure licensed Java EE application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801458/how-to-create-a-secure-licensed-j2ee-application)

You'll get alot of tips reading those questions and following the links

Answer (score 0):

When implementing licensing in a webapp installed on customer machines, make sure that its pre-compiled and preferably obfuscated. That way, the customer cannot change and/or make much sense of the license validation code. You could consider using our [Crypto](http://www.ssware.com/) licensing/obfuscation combo for this.