# Organize a python library as plugins

Tags: python, module

I would like to create a library, say foolib, but to keep different subpackages separated, so to have barmodule, bazmodule, all under the same foolib main package. In other words, I want the client code to be able to do

```
import foolib.barmodule
import foolib.bazmodule
```

but to distribute barmodule and bazmodule as two independent entities. Replace module with package as well... ba[rz]module can be a fukll fledged library with complex content.

The reason behind this choice is manifold:

- I would like a user to install only barmodule if he needs so.
- I would like to keep the modules relatively independent and lightweight.
- but I would like to keep them under a common namespace.

jQuery has a similar structure with the plugins.

Is it feasible in python with the standard setuptools and install procedure ?

Comment: I asked something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443146/how-do-i-protect-my-python-codebase-so-that-guests-cant-see-certain-modules-but

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for [namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python).  See also [PEP 382](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply create a foolib directory, add an `__init__.py` to it, and make each sub-module a `.py` file.

```
/foolib
    barmodule.py
    bazmodule.py
```

then you can import them like so:

```
from foolib import barmodule
barmodule.some_function()
```

Comment: Yes, this I know. My problem is not how to create a package containing two modules. My problem is to distribute them as two independent "sublibraries" part of the same library namespace.

Comment: Why not simply have a /plugins/ folder that users can drop plugins into and that gets checked when foolib is called?