# Add on to: How do I protect my Python codebase so that guests can't see certain modules but so it still works?

Tags: python, svn, permissions, source-code-protection

[How do I protect my Python codebase so that guests can't see certain modules but so it still works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443146/how-do-i-protect-my-python-codebase-so-that-guests-cant-see-certain-modules-but)

My question is an add on question posted on the page above.

If there are two svn directories; for example, src/private and src/public and internal users will have both public and private directories and things will just work fine.

The public users will have only src/public. Is it possible to import the src/private in **init**.py even though the user doesn't have it checked out? The user should be able to link to it to resolve any functional dependencies in src/private but, should not be able to view to content of the files.

Are there any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Give it up. It's essentially impossible to keep curious eyes out. For instance, look at the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module:

```
import dis
def foo(): print 'bar'
dis.dis(foo)
```

which would yield:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Voila - there are any strings you wanted to hide, simply by importing your modules. There are other modules and services that can do a pretty good job of converting such disassemblies into readable Python code.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? That is, what specifically are you trying to protect?

Comment: What I would like to do is basically the same as the original post. There are some python code (secret sauce) that I would like to safeguard. Temp employees/consultants should only be able to view/work with public code without having access to the private codebase. I understand that people with sole intention to steal the code will find a way but, a the idea is to make it harder for people to do so.

The codebase is in svn so, was just wondering if there is a straight forward way to do so, instead of rewriting the code in c/c++ or something else that would require signifiant effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can always move core functionality to some C or C++ module, and distribute only the compiled version of the module.

See http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html