# How to create Python module installer on Windows without including source files

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-installer, software-distribution

I would like to create a Windows Installer of my Python module (as explained here https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) without including the sources, meaning that the installer should only embed the Python bytecode.

I followed the solution explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444346/343201 and it only works for ZIP distributions. In other words, if I create a ZIP built distribution, I manage to exclude all sources and export only bytecode (.pyc). On the other hand, if I create a MSI/WININST built distribution, it will only contain sources (.py).

I looked at the output of bdist_wininst and looks like when creating a Windows installer, only  source files are exported, bytecode is ignored. Why? Is there a way to enforce the installer to embed only bytecode and no source files?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use py2exe, though it uses your script files. It will make a .exe file and the source code stays locked.

You can try every way around. Head over here and try http://www.py2exe.org/old/

Comment: I've already tried py2exe but it seems to have problems with libraries installed in egg format.

Comment: thats strange cos i dont have that problem. maybe some bug.