# run python module without the pyc extension

Tags: python

I have a compiled Python 2.6 program on Linux called abc.pyc. If I run

```
./abc.pyc
```

it runs fine. However if I rename it to abc (i.e, without the pyc extension) it fails to run. It gives the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named abc
```

How can I run my program without the .pyc extension?

**UPDATED:**
I want to run the compiled (pyc) version not the py version

Alternatively, I know I can compile modules to .so files using Cython, but can I compile my main Python program to something I can execute on a Linux platform? If so, a Cython command line example would be appreciated.

**UPDATED**
I've raised the Cython question as a separate question.

Comment: Useless question: why do you want to run it without the extension?

Comment: Becasue I want to add a little obfuscation - I know it's not much, but I would like it.

Comment: @mozza: Obfuscation to what end? This is not going to help you. See an existing discussion on protecting Python: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/118160

Comment: I know it's not very good, and easy to get around, but if it's possible I'd like to do it. Alternatively see my updated question re using Cython.

Comment: @mozza: very, very few Python programs can be compiled using Cython without major changes.

Comment: @Seth Johnson: I compiled 5 Python modules to .so files with just a few minor changes. Guess I was lucky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file named 'abc' which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/env python -m abc
```

or is that giving away too much valuable source code if they can read that?

Note also that .pyc files aren't portable between different versions of Python. Redistributing the source really would be best for that reason quite apart from causing less annoyance to your users and less cost to yourself (in support time if nothing else).

Comment: If using `-m`, you don't want the `pyc` extension (just the `abc` module name)

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that. I've yet to find any situation where I'd want to use `-m` so I'm not actually that used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rename the `.pyc` file - that is just a shortcut for the interpreter, so that it doesn't have to recompile already compiled code.

Instead, rename the `.py` file to `abc`, `chmod +x ./abc` and make sure the first line reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or even

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

From your explanation of the problem, I *guess* the `.pyc` file contains some linux loadable code that lets it be run as a binary, *providing* it can check the `.py` file for newer versions - and probably just starts the python interpreter to load itself or the source file (whichever is newer) and then go on with that. Who knows? Maybe the os specific docs will tell you. Maybe they won't.

Comment: I don't want to give the user the Python source. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: `.pyc` files can be decompiled.

Comment: I know, it's just a little obfuscation I would like to have.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to obfuscate your code, see [this discussion on protecting Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/118160). Basically, you can't wantonly distribute the Python bytecode which comprises the `.pyc` file, and there's no way to prevent people from peeking into your code.