# Are .pyds decompilable? - Python

Tags: python

I was wondering, if I export my game as an .exe and all the extra material is imported, turning it into a .pyd - can you decompile the .pyds?
Thanks!

Thank you people, I got my answer for any future people who need help:
.pyd files are just shared libraries
Any tools that allow people to inspect or disassemble a shared library will work on them as well. & for more info : [How hard to reverse engineer .pyd files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075042/how-hard-to-reverse-engineer-pyd-files)

Comment: Can this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075042/how-hard-to-reverse-engineer-pyd-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, `.pyd` files are just shared libraries (`.dll`s on Windows), with a different name. Any tools that allow people to inspect or disassemble a shared library will work on them as well.