# protect binary generated from py2exe python

Tags: python, py2exe

My project requires such that my python files have to be converted to py2exe. Fair and well , my py2exe is working. Assume my binary is called as "test.exe". I know that my test.exe contains all pyc files of my python file. What i want to do is , protect my text.exe, so that my source is not seen, in other words i dont want it be decompiled back, what can i do for this ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/1947535

Comment: Nothing. Even if you rewrite the application in C someone can inspect the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

In short: nothing. Any executable can always be reverse-engineered.

More in detail: do you really think your code is so valuable that people would go to spend months to do that?

Also keep in mind that if you import any module released under GPL, you would be doing something illegal in not having your code as GPL as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try to obfuscate your source code before building it. Have a look at http://freecode.com/projects/pyobfuscate . There always will be a way to decompile the binary but the resulting source would be very hard to read.

Comment: thanks, where do i find the usage of this , i googled around ,but i could not get much of it.

Comment: You can look the source there https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate, you'll need to install pyobfuscate using the provided setup.py then using a prompt "pyobfuscate <path>"