# How does DropBox protect its python code?

Tags: python, obfuscation, dropbox

I know that DropBox uses a lot of python code in its application, so i'm wondering how it protects the code from being stolen because it seems pretty difficult to obfuscate python code ([protecting python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)).

I've read about software that converts python code to executables (i.e. pyinstaller). Does DropBox use software like that to protect their code?

Comment: Dropbox is a webservice, so there's no need to obfuscate or protect the code. You can't access the code to begin with.

Comment: Their client application is written in python

Comment: This question is not off-topic: source code protection is a frequent topic in professional programming and falls well under [software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: The question should be reopened. Software protections is an important topic  which all developers and reversers should know alike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just tried to decompile it, but all decompilers failed, because they don't know the magic number used in dropbox pycs.
So I've googled and found this:
http://itooktheredpill.dyndns.org/2012/dropbox-decrypt/ ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009012100/http://itooktheredpill.irgendwo.org/2012/dropbox-decrypt/))

It says they have modified interpreter to encrypt modules and forbid access to code-objects. Plus they scramble opcodes.

Comment: Do you know if it is easy to decompile executables created by software like pyinstaller?

Comment: I don't know. Dropbox executable can be unzipped and there will be bunch of pyc's (which you cannot decompile for the mentioned above reason).

Comment: More on the subject http://blog.csnc.ch/2012/12/asfws-a-critical-analysis-of-dropbox-software-security/

Comment: Even more on this subject.  https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot13/woot13-kholia.pdf

Comment: link in answer (directing to itooktheredpill) is a 404