# How does this lambda/yield/generator comprehension work?

Tags: python, ssh, lambda, functional-programming, generator

I was looking through my codebase today and found this:

```
def optionsToArgs(options, separator='='):
    kvs = [
        (
            "%(option)s%(separator)s%(value)s" %  
            {'option' : str(k), 'separator' : separator, 'value' : str(v)}
        ) for k, v in options.items()
    ]
    return list(
        reversed(
            list(
                    (lambda l, t: 
                        (lambda f: 
                            (f((yield x)) for x in l)
                        )(lambda _: t)
                    )(kvs, '-o')
                )
            )
        )
```

It seems to take a dict of parameters and turn them into a list of parameters for a shell command. It looks like it's using yield inside a generator comprehension, which I thought would be impossible...?

```
>>> optionsToArgs({"x":1,"y":2,"z":3})
['-o', 'z=3', '-o', 'x=1', '-o', 'y=2']
```

How does it work?

Comment: Dang. Talk about unreadable code.

Comment: the funniest part is the `list(reversed(list(` part to get the `-o` switches right, though

Comment: Also all the lambdas could've been just `((lambda _: '-o')((yield x)) for x in kvs)`

Comment: ... and also the return statement could just be expressed as `[v for o in kvs for v in ["-o", o]]`.

Comment: This reminds me of duffs device. From this day on this will forever be known as Dogs device lol.

Comment: Looks like somebody got Maslow's hammer and kept banging until this came out.

Comment: Lol man for that project you're better with Lisp I suppose aha ..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since Python 2.5, `yield <value>` is an expression, not a statement.  See [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).

The code is hideously and unnecessarily ugly, but it's legal.  Its central trick is using `f((yield x))` inside the generator expression.  Here's a simpler example of how this works:

```
>>> def f(val):
...     return "Hi"
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(f((yield a)) for a in x)
[1, 'Hi', 2, 'Hi', 3, 'Hi']
```

Basically, using `yield` in the generator expression causes it to produce two values for every value in the source iterable.  As the generator expression iterates over the list of strings, on each iteration, the `yield x` first yields a string from the list.  The target expression of the genexp is `f((yield x))`, so for every value in the list, the "result" of the generator expression is the value of `f((yield x))`.  But `f` just ignores its argument and always returns the option string `"-o"`.  So on every step through the generator, it yields first the key-value string (e.g., `"x=1"`), then `"-o"`.  The outer `list(reversed(list(...)))` just makes a list out of this generator and then reverses it so that the `"-o"`s will come before each option instead of after.

However, there is no reason to do it this way.  There are a number of much more readable alternatives.  Perhaps the most explicit is simply:

```
kvs = [...] # same list comprehension can be used for this part
result = []
for keyval in kvs:
   result.append("-o")
   result.append(keyval)
return result
```

Even if you like terse, "clever" code, you could still just do

```
return sum([["-o", keyval] for keyval in kvs], [])
```

The `kvs` list comprehension itself is a bizarre mix of attempted readability and unreadability.  It is more simply written:

```
kvs = [str(optName) + separator + str(optValue) for optName, optValue in options.items()]
```

You should consider arranging an "intervention" for whoever put this in your codebase.

Comment: Looking at the history, it used to be: `return list(itertools.chain(*[['-o', v] for v in kvs]))`. It's unclear why it was changed from this.

Comment: @Dog The only change I'd do to the code in your comment is to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to avoid using the `*`(which can become expensive if the list is big)...

Comment: `list(f((yield a)) for a in x)` works here in Python 2.7, but I am relieved to see that it does not work in Python 3.9 and results in a `SyntaxError: 'yield' inside generator expression`

Answer (score 20):

Oh god. Basically, it boils down to this,:

```
def f(_):              # I'm the lambda _: t
    return '-o'

def thegenerator():   # I'm (f((yield x)) for x in l)
    for x in kvs:
        yield f((yield x))
```

So when iterated over, thegenerator yields `x` (a member of `kvs`) and then the return value of `f`, which is always `-o`, all in one iteration over `kvs`. Whatever `yield x` returns and what gets passed to `f` is ignored.

Equivalents:

```
def thegenerator():   # I'm (f((yield x)) for x in l)
    for x in kvs:
        whatever = (yield x)
        yield f(whatever)

def thegenerator():   # I'm (f((yield x)) for x in l)
    for x in kvs:
        yield x
        yield f(None)

def thegenerator():   # I'm (f((yield x)) for x in l)
    for x in kvs:
        yield x
        yield '-o'
```

There are lots of ways to do this much simpler, of course. Even with the original double-yield trick, the entire thing could've been

```
return list(((lambda _: '-o')((yield x)) for x in kvs))[::-1]
```