# Python follow up on yield as a function argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was reading this question

[How does this lambda/yield/generator comprehension work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955948/how-does-this-lambda-yield-generator-comprehension-work)

I would like to understand the language constructs in a bit more detail.
Why are the brackets necessary?

```
(yield 55)
```

as opposed to

```
yield 55
```

Why does it only work in a generator expression when it is being passed as an argument to a function?
If I do the following

```
 a = lambda x: 1
 a((yield 55))
 SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function
 # The error here implies that it must be used within a function... not a generator expression
```

When running the following:

```
a = lambda x: 1
list(a((yield 55)) for b in range(5))
[55,
 1,
 55,
 1,
 55,
 1,
 55,
 1,
 55,
 1]
```

Why does this yield produce a value? Who is calling next on it?
The order of the evaluation is not clear by the syntax.

Comment: Wait what, you can do that?

Comment: yes, that was my first impression too

Comment: For an extra surprise, add some square brackets around the generator expression (i.e. directly inside the parentheses for the `list()` call.

Comment: It doesn't have to be passed as an argument to a function. `list((yield 55) or b for b in range(5))` gives the same result. I don't know how the parenthesis around `yield 55` works, though.

Comment: should probably be considered as a bug.

Comment: @HåkenLid Who needs `zip()` when we can use this construct? :p