# How to hide the code while packaging

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I have created a small python application and trying to release it on PyPI.
I went through a couple of documents online:

1. [Quick Start to first release](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#create-your-first-release)
2. [Uploading Packages to the Package Index](http://docs.python.org/3.1/distutils/uploading.html)

But I want to hide the code of my application from the user who will install it using pip/easy_install. What are my options to achieve this ? Any online tutorials that I can go through ?

Comment: You don't have any. Either you distribute the code or you don't distribute it at all.

Comment: I'm no expert on PyPI, but AFAIK, it's an open source repo, meaning you have to open your source code. If you really want to commercialize your code, compile it into a binary and distribute that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, PyPI does *not* set any license requirements. But it doesn't *protect* distributed packages either; release on PyPI means you are using a fully open distribution channel.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: That means you can upload commercial-license code too but you cannot expect people to pay attention and heed the license when they install your package.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. **PyPI is where you will want to release your distribution if you intend to make your project public.**