# Running a Python Program Hiding the Source

Tags: python

When I run a program from a USB memory, and remove the USB memory the program still goes on running (I mean with out really copying the program into the Windows PC).
However, does the program make its copy inside the Windows in any hidden location or temporary folder while running by the python IDLE. From where the python IDLE receive the code to be running after removing the USB memory? I am going to run python program in a public shared PC so I do not want anyone find out my code, I just want to run it, and get the result next day. Does someone can get my code even I remove the USB memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: my question is no more related to the link you provided, my question is about to run from USB memery, and after clicking RUN, removing the USB from the host PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways someone can get your program, even if you remove the USB drive.

- They can install a program that triggers when a USB stick is inserted, search the stick for `.py` files, and copies them to disk.
- If the Python installation you're using is on the disk instead of the USB drive, they can replace the Python executable with a wrapper that saves copies of any file the Python interpreter opens.
- Your program is going to go into RAM, and depending on what it does and what else is using the machine, it may get swapped to disk. An attacker may be able to read your program out of RAM or reconstruct it from the swap file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing something you probably shouldn't be doing.  Depending on how much people want your code they could go as far as physically freezing the ram and doing a forensic IT analysis.  In short, you can't prevent code cloning on a machine you don't administer.