# How to compile c, c++ and python code as “Released/Final” version?

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, compilation

I want to know if there are ways to compile C, C++ and Python code in order to not be able to reverse engineering it over Linux or not?

I have heard there are some ways over Windows to do it, but I am working on Linux.

I want to compile my code securely, as released or final version.

**UPDATE**

At least I want to make it hard for usual users to disassemble,

I am using GCC for C and GPP for C++, also I would be thankful if you introduce me best compiler for Python.

Comment: It depends of which compiler you're using.

Comment: gcc for c and c++ and also introduce me best one for python...Thanks

Comment: Your question did just get deleted. Please revise your question and come back later.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer I wanted to make some changes

Comment: try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Anti-debugging

Comment: You could encrypt executable file with long random password, and decrypt it on the fly when the user run it, plus some anti-debugging technologies, I think this could make your code pretty safe. DO NOT ask me how to do these stuff, I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there are ways to compile c, c++ and python code in order to not be able to reverse engineering it over Linux or not?

You could always obfuscate the code, but know this: A dedicated reverse engineer can not be stopped. As someone else once said on this site: You can't protect your code technologically, only legally.

> I want to compile my c, c++ and python code securely... as released or final version...

Well, as far as python is concerned, you could always ship the software as an executable created by an exe packager such as py2exe or freeze. [Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code).

> also I would be thankful if you introduce me best compiler for Python

In the Python world, you aren't talking about a compiler, rather, about a specific implementation. Most people use the reference [`cpython`](http://www.python.org) implementation. There are also alternatives such as [`pypy`](http://www.pypy.org) or jython,
but they are not dedicated compilers, rather, full blown virtual machines.

Comment: Is there any switches in gcc for c and c++ or some tricks? I did search bot not found

Comment: @MortezaLSC Well, you might want to use something like `-O2`. Please refer [to this site](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for all the available optimizations in gcc.

Comment: Thank you very much,At least I want to make it hard for usual users to disassemble,

Comment: @MortezaLSC If you found that this answers your question, consider to mark it as the accepted answer, so that the question gets closed.

Comment: Ok,,I want to do some searches and let other guys to help...Then surely I will accept :)

Comment: I am really thankful...your answer and comment is really helpful to me...very good

Comment: @MortezaLSC, people can still answer if you accept one. If there is a better answer, you can (and should) choose again. Not that there's any hurry to accept :)

Comment: Thanks again...any other answers are welcome as well