# How do you add authentication to a docker image?

Tags: authentication, docker

Title says it all. Basically when I run an image is it possible to require authentication, for example the image won't run without a proper public key and the image's contents are encrypted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006727/encrypted-and-secure-docker-containers

Comment: This question is more concerned with code obfuscation. I'm saying if you have the public key to the image you can read/run whatever you like.

Comment: What is the reason you are encrypting? Who are you protecting the contents from?

Comment: Other users who have access to the same system.

Comment: Won't file permissions solve that?

Comment: Not if an admin creates the containers. Basically you'd ssh into the machine and run the container that corresponds to you. I can see other people's containers but can't access them unless I have their key. The admin is agnostic to who logs into the machine.

Comment: Like the Unix philosophy goes: Do one thing and do it well, I'm not sure it fits into Docker. Maybe you are looking for an application server or web ui that can run Docker containers. If a user can access the docker daemon, it won't matter if the image or filesystem was encrypted