# compile .py file to .c file then convert to .so file

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I'm trying to compile python file with Cython and it's compiled to .c file
Then I'm using gcc to encryption What is the best way to do this

I'm doing it like this :

```
cython -a test.py
```

then :

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o test.so test.c
```

but someone told me he decryption my file and see the code
What is the best way to encrypt with GCC

thanks.

Comment: Who said you, that gcc can be used for encryption? It is a compiler, not a protector.

Comment: Related, near dupe with answers worth reviewing: [How do I protect Python code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov hmmm, how can I encrypt it

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov what if I use : gcc -lcrypt

Comment: Then you will add to link libcrypt.so nothing more. Look, you should believe -- gcc is really just compiler, nothing else. Take upx, armadillo, or any other professional packer/protector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling is not the same thing as encryption.  Compiling code is intended to make it executable by a machine or a virtual machine / language runtime.  Although it is usually not possible to *decompile* a compiled program into the original source code (or even something close to it), it is often possible to recover something resembling the original source code.

The *extent* to which this is possible depends on a number of factors including:

- the original language
- the compiler used
- the number of *intermediate representations* involved in the compilation process
- how aggressively the compiler has optimised the code (usually a compiler option)
- whether debugging symbols have been stripped from the resultant executable

Comment: is there any way to encrypt .c file

Comment: or encrypt python file

Comment: @vevo demo: Yes, but neither will then be usable by their respective compilers.  The best you can do is to obfuscate the code (which some programmers do unintentionally).

Comment: @vevodemo what is your goal?  What do you want to achieve, and why?

Comment: I'm make some script with Python and some people stole my work :-(

I need to some thing to protect my code just this

Comment: @vevodemo it is not easy to prevent people copying your code, especially with scripting languages like Python where the source code itself constitutes the usual executable form of the program.  But assuming you have copyright in the code, you may have legal remedy.  Alternatively you could use an instrument like copyleft to make your code available but require other people to publish their changes when they redistribute the program.  (Disclaimer: *I am not a lawyer*)

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer ... LOOOL .ok thank u In my country there is no copyright :-D.

Answer (score 0):

What encryption? There isn't any. What you have produced is a shared library - a `.so` file.

This can be inspected for symbols and disassembled but you can't trivially recover the original Python or C code.

Comment: is there any way to encrypt .c file ?

Comment: Yes, but it will not be of use because it still requires compilation before it can be executed. In general it is impractical because it will always be possible for a determined user to reverse engineer any software.