# Is it possible to compile Python source codes to protect code from unauthorized access?

Tags: python, security, compilation, bytecode, code-access-security

For example, I'm a developer, who created some application (e.g., `django application`) for free, using python. I want to share my application with other guys. But I don't want share source code. I wish to have full control on my program.

Is it possible to `compile Python source codes to bytecodes` to protect code from unauthorized access? I could share bytecodes of my program. Note, that I understand, that it is not absolute protection of source code. But is there a better way?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/42346

Comment: @bernie, I didn't find any advices there :(

Comment: Use Cython (or something similar) to compile python to C code, then distribute your app as python binary libraries (pyd) instead.
http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm

Comment: If you want to "share your program", perhaps you can do so by deploying it "in the cloud" as a service.

Comment: @FredMitchell, unfortunately, PaaS or SaaS are not suitable for my case.