# How to deploy ODOO without source code

Tags: odoo

i'm trying to deploy ODOO without source code, but I can't and I don't know if it's possible. So, I need to know if it's possible to deploy ODOO without source code? By example, only with .pyc file instead .py

I need to separate the code of the compiled files, because I do not want that everyone with access to the server have access to the source code. Only developers can access.

Best regards

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: Hi @yannicksoldati I need to separate the code of the compiled files, because I do not want that everyone with access to the server have access to the source code. Only developers can access

Comment: I think it will be easiest to give permission on folder, a special group for the source code.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, these users can authenticate as root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. It's very easy to get back the source code from `.pyc` files.

Longer answer: you may not have the right to do so. Odoo <= 8 is licensed under the AGPL and you *must* allow users to get the source code. Odoo >= 9 is under LGPL, and unless you host the code yourself, you have to give *your customer* access to the source code (note that *your customer* is different from *end users*)