# Is it possible to write closed source android program with python?

Tags: android, python

I am making an android game using Python.An i was wondering if it is possible to write closed source android program with python?

Comment: Of course it is possible. What, precisely, is your concern?

Comment: Closed source stands for the idea that no one without authorization can see the code you used to create a piece of software. Once a computer program has been built what you really do is give out a copy of the binary version (only a computer can understand this).

Comment: I want to earn money by adding advertisements and making in-game sales with the game i made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I'd like to know is how can I make a binary version. And can android read binary version(I think answer is "yes" but I asked just to be sure)

Comment: You really want to do Android development. Python isn't really the solution here, unless you are unwilling to learn Java. Android doesn't have a widely installed Python interpreter, but has a pretty good ability to run Android apps. Check out Android Studio if you haven't tried any Android development before.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't re-using code under some sort of open-source license you don't have to post your code for anyone to see.

I believe you mean that you want to write Python code that can't be read by  humans. That is pretty difficult in Python and the best you can really hope for is obfuscation.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. How can I obfuscate by the way?

Comment: Theres a few different ways to do it, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code) for some better info; I've never bothered to try it myself.