# Protect python code in raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, security, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm a few weeks away from finishing up a python project written for raspberry pi 2 B, on raspbian os.

The only thing I'm still afraid is, how to protect my code from others?

Anyone can connect a screen with hdmi cable, and easily access my raspberry pi.

In windows, just compile your code as executable (.exe) file and all done. But what should I do in linux?

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: Thanks dear, I checked your link, and it looks like no way to protect the whole code, according to the accepted solution. It's really a big problem.