# Python Compressor

Tags: python, parsing

I'm looking for a way how can I compress python code.

Ideal solution converts

```
def sum_of_two(first, second):
    ''' sum of two'''
    return first + second
```

Into

```
def a(b,c):
    return b+c
```

Any ideas of ways how I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: You want to look for "python obfuscation".  It'll be easy from there.

Comment: Are you looking for something that looks at the code and rewrites it?

Comment: Wow, you'll need to parse Python and analyze the code's structure. Good luck with that! See you in two years or later!

Comment: This is especially tricky to do in Python thanks to its dynamic features. If I do `d = {"first": 23, "second": 42}; print(sum_of_two(**d))`, it will work with the original code but crash after applying a compression algorithm that leaves string literals alone. And a compression algorithm that can determine what string literals should be replaced, would need to have human-level intelligence or above.

Comment: Better dupe, but too late: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code