# How to add security to a python script so that the script can be opened using a one time key

Tags: python, security

I have had trouble trying to protect my software from being copied by another person. I want to be able to give the software to them then send them a one time key to open the software making it workable, preventing it from being copied and distributed. Any help appreciated. Want to make a login server for cutomers to login to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a biggy. Make an account server. Open an internet port on it. Make a lib which will send (use Python ssl lib) the product key, login and password (all three userinput). If the server accepts them (account exists, password is correct) it will register that key to that account. Key will be in the database, and when it is redeemed then it is exchanged for game copy license on your server. Then game will check whether the loginned account has that game, and if it has then the game starts. For antitamper use Cython. DeNuvo can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrtebUkUssc. Helpful link I thought for sockets and contacting outside account server. Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIPZoZheMTo