# When deploying keras model in client's machine, how can I prevent clients from getting or modifying my keras model?

Tags: encryption, machine-learning, model

Is there any way to do some encryption in the model of the machine learning so that this model still can work but clients cannot extract the model? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: read this: as you are asking what turns out to be a very well known question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code, also you can go ahead and close this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)