# How to protect Cython .pyd?

Tags: python, cython, obfuscation, pyd

I have the following **foo.pyx** file which contains a cdef class:

```
cdef class Foo:

    cdef int test_1(self):
        ...
        return 0

    cdef int test_2(self):
        ...
        return 0
```

And the corresponding **foo.pxd**:

```
cdef class Foo:

    cdef int test_1(self)
    cdef int test_2(self)
```

I would like to protect my resulting pyd to only export the **test_1** function. Because (correct me if I'm wrong) both functions are importable in others pyx file via cimport. To do so they must be "exported" in their pyd, meaning they are available from outside the pyd.

I tried removing **test_2** from the declarations (in foo.pxd) but I get a compilation error.

My questions:

- Is there a way to control what is exported from the pyd?
- If not what can I do to protect or obfsucate function names that are exported?

My fear is that someone seeing the exported functions signature of the pyd, would guess what they do.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: Why would it be bad if someone using a library guessed what the functions of the library do?

Comment: "what can I do to protect or obfsucate function names that are exported" - can't you just *choose a different name* yourself?