# How to protect/encrypt a python module?

Tags: python, encryption

- My project is open sourced, except for a single module where I don't want people to know the implementation. Actually, I don't mind one or two people cracking the thing open if they are determined enough, but I want most to give up at the first sight.
- I only want the implementation of that single module to be hidden, the interface still fully usable if people want to contribute to the project. That is to say, I want people to be able to do things like:

```py
import my_hidden_module

my_hidden_module.do_stuff()
```

- My project mostly runs on Windows so Windows-exclusive suggestions are ok.
- I'm totally new to this hiding code thing so I don't know where to start. It would be appreciated if someone could give me a direction to look into.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use classes and private variables or
2) use **name** =='**main**', but that will not implement the code on interface
3) looks dumb but you can comment on top of that function to not to be CHANGED
else you can see - [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)