# How to package my Python flask project so the client can't see the code and When client start the his windows 10 professional

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

I have develop python application, I want to deploy in client system so he cant see my code. How to do packaging (.whl) of project.

When client start the his system (windows 10 professional), my package should start and ready to use rest API to client

I am attaching my folder structure please help me
[image]

Comment: A wheel file not magically make your code invisible.

Comment: @KlausD. you means code visible in wheel file?

Comment: It's quite easy to obtain the source code from python packages, even if they only contain the compiled object files (usually packages are just a zip of the source code!) See e.g.  [uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/).  You're looking for obfuscation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

follow the link [for more details](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

If you want to create a package file you can use the following command.

```
python setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

Answer (score 0):

A wheel is called a binary package because it is targetted to a specific architecture and can contain binary library. But those binary libraries are built from C source code, not from Python. For the rest, a whl file is just a zip file having a special structure, which means that it is enough to unzip it to directly read all the Python files, because it contains all what is required for the project, those pre-compiled binary objects *and* the Python source code (thanks to Thom Wiggers for noticing).

That being said, a .whl file is a useful package format that can be built with `setuptools` and its `bdist_wheel` extension. When both are installed you use:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

with an appropriate `setup.py`.

A full explaination would be far beyond what can be written in a SO answer, so if you want to go that way, I can only advise you to read the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/), specifically the [Tool recommendations guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/) and the [Packaging and distributing projects guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/)

Comment: I want to emphasize that `.whl` files typically contain *both* the pre-compiled binary object files *and* the python source code. The OP appears to want to hide their source code...

Comment: @ThomWiggers: Thanks for noticing. I have edited my post with your comment. Hope it is more clear now...