# How Can I Hide / Encrypted my Python(Django or Flask) sourcecode from Clients?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, django-2.2, security-constraint

I want to hide my source code from my clients. because only buy the license of my software. Anyone would like to share the Idea of hiding python source code hiding. If anyone know about this please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Comment: No such thing. Either you own the server, or they have the source, there's no third option.