# How to compile a .py program into exe so that it is not decompiled

Tags: python, exe

With "auto py to exe" I normally compile .py to .exe. However, my program was decompiled and published. I acted quickly and up to 3/4 people downloaded it. Back to the topic...
How could I compile a .py program into .exe so that it cannot be decompiled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

Use Cython to generate .pyd file and then import your .pyd file (like a normal python file) in a normal python file (.py). Doing that when you use pyinstaller only your normal py file will be accessible if your exe is open.

ex:

myScript.py

```
def main():
  print("Hello")
```

Use cython on myScript.py to generate a .pyd file

And then a normal python file to import your .pyd file:
runMyScript.py

```
import myScript #the .pyd file

#run your script
myScript.main()
```

Then use pyinstaller to package your app

Comment: Hey ! Sorry to reply so late ... Can you instruct me on how to generate the .pyd file. I can't do this.

BTW I think I installed Cython correctly