# Python script to execute on Raspbian (Code Protection)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, compilation, raspbian

I have a python script/app which is running on RPi in `.py` file. Now I need to share this app, but I want to protect the code.

On windows I always export it to `.exe` and share it in order to make it executable and protect the code (mostly using [python auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)python auto-py-to-exe). What about Raspbian? Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical aspects if you can obfuscate python sourcecorde are already widely discussed for example in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users).

If you just want to make it a little bit harder for someone to read your code compiling it as `.pyc` could be a solution or maybe your `.exe` export even runs with WINE on raspbian.

Comment: In the end, I compile it to `.pyc` and send it like that. I found some of those "decompilers" that can basically translate the code back to `.py` but I didn't research any further. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your reply, it is interesting for me to read what solution you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Python, being a byte-code-compiled interpreted language, is very difficult to lock down.

So you have to apply ordinary commercial methods.

1. Licenses or any other something like that.
2. Offer web based service like [PaaS, SaaS](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-paas)