# How to create exe file from Python that is impossible to decode back to python?

Tags: python, windows, executable

I am kinda new to turning python files to executables and thats why I am asking it. Is there any way to make executable file from Python, that is impossible to decode back? Sorry if this dumb question or whatever

I did some research and wanna ask if Nuitka will help me solve my problem. I also use selenium, moviepy, os, requests, random libraries if that makes sense. I am on windows

I don't want to leak source code. I guess thats the question

Comment: It is not really possible. Any code can be decompiled into something more-or-less readable with varying amounts of effort required. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to make an app, and give it to untrusted man, but i dont want to leak an app at all, and I'm trying to find way to accomplish that thing. Also, i can just make webapp, but my html,css,javascript skills are so poor

Comment: You don't want to leak hidden information (e.g. passwords) hard-coded in the application, or you just don't want to leak your source code?

Comment: I don't want to leak source code

Comment: Is this something you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users ?

Comment: Short answer: it can't be done. On the other hand, unless you are doing something really special, probably no one would take your code anyway, even if it was made free.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate that