# Simple, pythonic way to print out function invoked during a python3 execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, call-graph

Do we have a python3, pythonic way to print out function invoked during a python execution? For example, I run a main function on a third-party, relatively large library. I need to print out all functions called. Eventually, I hope to remove code that is irrelevant to a specific execution of code. I know from [Is there a tool that removes functions that are not used in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087758/is-there-a-tool-that-removes-functions-that-are-not-used-in-python) that this was difficult in general years ago.

There may be good answer at [How do I print functions as they are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called), but maybe outdated for python3?

Comment: Do the solutions proposed in the question you link not work? Or do they?

Comment: Yeah I think so, but it looks complex and maybe old-fashioned

Comment: The proper name for what you're looking for is a "call graph". The question I linked to has several good answers.