# How to make an encrypted executable file

Tags: python, ubuntu, encryption, bin

I have made a tool/program on Ubuntu written in Python. I want to give this to my friend to test on his PC, but I don't want to share the source code.

This program has many folders and many `.py` files. Is there a way to turn all this code into one encrypted executable file (like a binary file)?

Comment: How is it encrypted? It's no more encrypted than writing in Chinese to a Chinese person so he can actually understand you... the correct word is probably "obfuscation".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: Look at [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It will allow you to create the executable output, but from what I can tell not obfuscate it. As the link above points out, however, you might not get the protection you expect from obfuscation anyway.

Comment: thanks for cx_freeze...it worked for windows but I need it in Ubuntu. `import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "testing cx_freeze.",
    executables = [Executable("a.py")])` this is my code. It can make a executable but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always *obfuscate* the source code. Here you can use the tool [pyobfuscate](http://freecode.com/projects/pyobfuscate). To know more about obfuscation, go to [obfuscating Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576963/python-code-obfuscation) and information about [protecting Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code).