# How to compile a python script to an executable?

Tags: python, compilation, exe

I know a way to do this is using pyinstaller, however, after some [research](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller), I found out that a pyinstaller exe can be reverse engineered to get the original python script.

Do you know a way to compile a python script into an executable which can be shared with anyone ,even if they **don't have** the dependencies I used, or python, installed, and **can not** be reverse engineered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two other threads talking about this, maybe you would like them:

> [How to make an encrypted executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297725/how-to-make-an-encrypted-executable-file)
>
> https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-protect-my-Python-code-but-still-make-it-available-to-run